# Incremental logic on DBT BigQuery using insert_overwrite

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

**Requirement:**

We get data having filenames in a specific format which implies which month's data it is (**e.g.** retailername20230701), we need to make it incremental such that if there is any update made in the source for any of the historical files then that particular file's data should be fully deleted and the data based on the latest load_timestamp should be inserted and any new files will just be processed (i.e. appended as-is).

> **Note:** There is no unique_key for the dataset, it is very uncertain to predict which column's data will change.

**sample_table:**

| name | file_name | load_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | abc20231201 | 2023-12-01 09:46:48.021448 UTC |
| Antony | xyz20231203 | 2023-12-03 10:26:12.021338 UTC |
| Messi | abc20231201 | 2023-12-01 09:46:48.021448 UTC |

> ***Note:** If data is updated for the existing filename, it should take the filename and data in it according to the latest load*_*timestamp and delete the old file* records completely. *(e.g. Mark should be replaced with Jack)*

| Name | file_name | load_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | abc20231201 | 2024-01-02 10:16:28.041229 UTC |
| Messi | abc20231201 | 2024-01-02 10:16:28.041229 UTC |

**Expected Result**:

| Name | file_name | load_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Antony | xyz20231203 | 2023-12-03 10:26:12.021338 UTC |
| Jack | abc20231201 | 2024-01-02 10:16:28.041229 UTC |
| Messi | abc20231201 | 2024-01-02 10:16:28.041229 UTC |

I have referred this [doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models) and implemented the below code:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        partition_by = {'field': 'load_timestamp','data_type': 'timestamp'},
        incremental_strategy= 'insert_overwrite'
    )
}}

select * from sample_table

{% if is_incremental() %}

  -- this filter will only be applied on an incremental run
  -- (uses > to include records whose timestamp occurred since the last run of this model)

  where load_timestamp >= (select max(load_timestamp) from {{ this }})

{% endif %}
```

I did not get the expected result using the above code and I'm not sure how to modify the code to pass the file_name to delete the corresponding old records & insert the records based on the latest load_timestamp. Can somebody help me to resolve this?

Comment: Why did Mark get replaced with Jack but Messi didn't? Can you provide a clearer example of how to perform it?

the `insert_overwrite` behavior will replace any data in the same time_partition, or insert new records if detected as new. 

if you want to modify old records and insert new ones then you should select `merge` strategy

Comment: @ChiếnLê, thanks for your prompt response! the aim here is to delete the entire file if it has the same name as the previously existing filename and to reload the file with the updated data with the latest timestamp, and if there are any new filenames that gets added down the lane it has to be appended too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried partitioning by `file_name` instead of the `load_timestamp`?

```
  partition_by = {'field': 'file_name', 'data_type': 'string'}
```

This approach will isolate records for each `file_name` then you can write a  query to get the `MAX(load_timestamp)` of each file so you can filter out later dates in your main `SELECT` query, although this method keeps historical records instead of deleting them. It's just a habit of mine to keep change-logs for back tracking or troubleshooting purposes.

The `MERGE` suggestion by @[Chiến Lê](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17069463/chi%E1%BA%BFn-l%C3%AA) is also a good option to manage complex scenarios as this will allow more control over updates.